# How to differentiate Residual sum of square

Tags: calculus, statistics, derivatives, matrix-calculus

Residual sum of square (RSS) is defined as

RSS(beta) = $(y-X * beta)^t (y-X * beta)X$

While differentiating RSS(beta) w.r.t to beta to find the minimum value of the function, author  reaches the conclusion that

$X^T(y-X * beta) = 0$

Where $X$ is an $N*p$ matrix, $Y$ is a $N*1$ vector and $beta$ is $p*1$ vector.

Can someone please point me how this conclusion was reached ?

Note: This is from the book Elements of statistical.

Answer (score 1):

Write the RSS in terms of the [Frobenius (:) product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Frobenius_product) then find its differential and gradient wrt $\beta$
$$\eqalign{
  R &= (X\beta-y):(X\beta-y) \cr\cr
 dR &= 2\,(X\beta-y):(X\,d\beta) \cr
    &= 2\,X^T(X\beta-y):d\beta \cr\cr
 \frac{\partial R}{\partial\beta} &= 2\,X^T(X\beta-y) \cr
}$$
Now set the gradient equal to zero, like the author does, and solve for $\beta$.

If you're uncomfortable with the Frobenius products in the above derivation, you can substitute the equivalent trace function, $A:B={\rm tr}(A^TB)$

Comment: this is a stupid question from my end, but 1.) how did ($y-X\beta$) become ($X\beta-y$), 2.)  isn't Frobenius product normally denoted $\left<X,Y\right>_F$